# How to turn STATISTICS TIME ON\OFF using variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I need to use A LOT of `set statistics time on` and `set statistics time off` so I can check every steps' running time. Is there any way I can usr a variable to replace `ON` and `OFF`?

```
CREATE Procedure CPP_InsertOneRows
(@turnStatistics bit = 0
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @onOrOff CHAR(3);
    IF @turnStatistics = 1
    BEGIN 
        SET @onOrOff = 'ON';
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SET @onOrOff = 'OFF';
    END

    SET STATISTICS TIME OFF -- how can I use @onOrOff to replace the 'OFF' here?
    SET STATISTICS IO Off
```

Am I using it correctly? Or is there other method to do this? Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do the actual turning on/off within the `IF`:

```sql
IF @turnStatistics = 1 
    SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
ELSE
    SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;

...

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
```

You cannot use a variable for the value of `OFF`/`ON`, it must be a literal.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to check the time taken for each step of your code you can use following mehtod

```
Print 'Step 1 started'
print CONVERT (TIME, GETDATE()) 
 WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'; -- function 
Print 'Step 1 ended'
print CONVERT (TIME, GETDATE()) 

Print 'Step 2 started'
print CONVERT (TIME, GETDATE()) 
 WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';  --- function 
Print 'Step 2 ended'
print CONVERT (TIME, GETDATE())
```

[image]

make sure you remove this after your testing or uses @trace parameter if this @trace=1 only you will run this by default is set to @trace=0 (with if blocks)